# Все делители числа

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Дан следующий прототип функции, которая должна возвращать вектор всех делителей числа `x` **в отсортированном порядке** за `O(n^1/2)`:

```
auto foo(int x) { // x > 0
   std::vector<int> factors;

   // input your code here

   return factors;
}
```

Вот что я написал:

```
auto foo(int x) {
    std::vector<int> factors;

    for(int k = 1; k <= std::sqrt(x); ++k) 
        if (x % k == 0) {
            factors.push_back(k);

            if (k != std::sqrt(x))
                factors.push_back(x / k);
        }

    return factors;
}
```

Но вектор получается неотсортированный. Есть идея добавлять маленькие значения в один вектор, а большие в другой, а потом их соединить в один, но непонятно, как это сделать без копирования, не превысив заданную сложность.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, у вас все равно получится не больше корня из n делителей в каждом векторе, так что копирование вам опять же даст ту же сложность - можно смело его использовать.

Но можно просто взять дек, а работать начать от корня вниз, к 1, и соответственно найденные делители запихивать с разных сторон.

Более сложный в реализации - но и более быстрый - вариант заключается в поиске всех простых делителей и генерации из них полного списка делителей.

Comment: Можете привести реализацию с деком и последним вариантом?

Comment: Послушайте, для дека просто разверните цикл - `for(int k = std::sqrt(x); k >=1; --k)`, ну а дальше - `factors.push_back(k);` заменить на `factors.push_front(k);`. По сути все. Последний вариант, простите уж, реализовывать не стану, времени нет. Он действительно куда сложнее - в части генерации всех доступных делителей в отсортированном порядке; я его указал просто как идею.

Comment: всё, понял, спасибо